# Databricks Delta cache contains a stale footer and stale page entries Error

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I have been getting notebook failures intermittingly relating to querying a `TEMPORARY VIEW` that is selecting from a parquet file located on a ADLS Gen2 mount.

```
Delta cache contains a stale footer and stale page entries for the file dbfs:/mnt/container/folder/parquet.file, these will be removed (4 stale page cache entries). Fetched file stats (modificationTime: 1616064053000, fromCachedFile: false) do not match file stats of cached footer and entries (modificationTime: 1616063556000, fromCachedFile: true).
    at com.databricks.sql.io.parquet.CachingParquetFileReader.checkForStaleness(CachingParquetFileReader.java:700)
    at com.databricks.sql.io.parquet.CachingParquetFileReader.close(CachingParquetFileReader.java:511)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.SpecificParquetRecordReaderBase.close(SpecificParquetRecordReaderBase.java:327)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.close(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:164)
    at com.databricks.sql.io.parquet.DatabricksVectorizedParquetRecordReader.close(DatabricksVectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:484)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator.close(RecordReaderIterator.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator.hasNext(RecordReaderIterator.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1$$anon$2.getNext(FileScanRDD.scala:291)
```

The a datafactory `Copy Data` activity is performed to Source (from mssql table) and Sink (Parquet file) using snappy compression before the notebook command is executed.  No other activities or pipelines write to this file.  However, multiple notebooks will perform selects against this same parquet file.

[image: SELECT FROM paquet.]

From what I can tell from the error message, the delta cache is older than the parquet file itself.  Is there a way to turn off the caching for this particular file (it is very small dataset) or invalidate the cache prior to the `Data Copy` activity? I am aware of the [`CLEAR CACHE`](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-aux-cache-clear-cache.html) command but this does it for all tables and not specifically temp views.

Answer (score 2):

We have a similar process and we have been having the exact same problem.

If you need to invalidate the cache for a specific file/folder you can use something like the following Spark-SQL command:

```
REFRESH {file_path}
```

Where file path is either the path through the dbfs or your mount.

Worth noting is that if you specify a folder instead of a file all files within that folder (recursively) will be refreshed.

This also may very well not solve your problem. It seems to have helped us, but that is more of a gut feeling as we have not been actively looking at the frequency of these failures.

[The documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-aux-cache-refresh-table)

Our Specs:
Azure
Databricks Runtime 7.4
Driver: Standard_L8s_v2
Workers: 24 Standard_L8s_v2